# Check sort order of values Ruby with Capybara

Tags: ruby, capybara

I have a table that has columns that can be sorted ascending / descending.

Is there a way in which I can check the sort is correct?

I was thinking of having a sorted list stored in an array, then storing each item from the table into a second array, zipping together with the Ruby `zip` method and making a comparison.

Would this be the best way or is there a simpler way?

The values are reference numbers like so:

```
AUT001
AUT002
AUT003
AUT004
CCT113
CCT114
CCT115
```

Comment: Couldn't you just `arr1 == arr2`?

Comment: Oh my god, yes! Sorry for the brain fart and time wasting question